# function vowel_count that take a string as inputs count the number of occurrence and prints the occurrence

Tags: python

I need to print the number of vowel occurrences in the string. I am able to count and print them in one line but I am having issue to print 'a,e,i,o and u'  respectively on occurrence. I am not allowed to use any built in function. Can some one please guide or let me know what I am missing. Below is my code.

```
vowels = 'aeiou'
def vowel_count(txt):
    for vowel in vowels:
        print (txt.count(vowel),end ='')
    return
```

It will print the occurrence but I am not able to add anything in front of it. Lets say I pass `le tour de france` it should print 
`a,e,i,o and u appear , respectively ,1,3,0,1,1 times`.

Please let me know if any thing is unclear, thanks.

Comment: Why `return` ??? What's your expected output?

Comment: if user give vowel_count(python is awesome) it should print as below.

a,e,i,o and u appear respectively 1,2,1,2,0 times.

Comment: What's stopping you printing before the for loop, `print('a,e,i,o and u appear, respectively, ', end='')` and `print('times')` at the end of the loop?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, thats where i am having issues.
    
    print('a,e,i,o and u appear, respectively, ', end='')
    print (txt.count(vowel))

i get below output

    a,e,i,o and u appear, respectively, 1
    a,e,i,o and u appear, respectively, 2
    a,e,i,o and u appear, respectively, 1
    a,e,i,o and u appear, respectively, 2
    a,e,i,o and u appear, respectively, 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using list comprehension, the following can be achieved:

```
vowels = 'aeiou'
def vowel_count(txt):
    counts = map(txt.count, vowels)
    return ", ".join(vowels) + " appear, respectively, " + ",".join(map(str, counts)) + " times"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just print before and after the loop your top and tail text:

```
def vowel_count(txt):
    print('a,e,i,o and u appear , respectively ', end='')
    for vowel in vowels:
        print(',', txt.count(vowel), sep='', end='')
    print(' times')

>>> vowel_count('le tour de france')
a,e,i,o and u appear , respectively ,1,3,0,1,1 times
```

But isn't print a built in function? I'm not sure how you can complete this task without using any built in functions.

Comment: I think OP doesn't want to use any built-in functions that does the vowel counting

Comment: Hmm, isn't `count()` a function too?

Comment: What I mean is, OP doesn't want a built-in `vowel_count` function